# How do I make these widgets fill the mother frame?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to get these entry and text widgets to take up all the room in their frame, but it seems that their size is fixed. Grid tools is not helping.

```
                l = Frame(self, bg=ard)
                l.grid(row=0, column = 2, rowspan = 2, columnspan = 3, sticky = ALL)
                self.enter = Entry(l, width=100)
                self.enter.grid(row=0, column=2, rowspan=1, columnspan=3, sticky=ALL)
                self.outro = Text(l, width=100, height=100)
                self.outro.grid(row=1, column=2, rowspan=1, columnspan=3, sticky=ALL)
```

### Here's the whole program just in case:

```
from tkinter import *
import os.path
root = Tk()


ALL = N+S+W+E

buttons = ['Red', 'Blue', 'Green', 'Black', 'Open']
def colorgen():
    while True:
        yield "red"
        yield "blue"
        yield "green"
        yield "orange"
        yield "purple"

color = colorgen()

def coordinates(event):
    print("X:{0} Y:{1}".format(event.x, event.y))



class Application(Frame):


    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.master.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid(sticky=ALL)
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):    

        for r in range(2):
            self.rowconfigure(r, weight=1)

            ccount = 0
            for c in range(5):
                self.columnconfigure(c, weight=1)
                ard=next(color)
                if c==0:
                    button0 = Button(self, text=buttons[c], command = lambda: self.changeoutro(0)).grid(row=4, column=c, sticky=ALL)
                elif c==1:
                    button1 = Button(self, text=buttons[c], command = lambda: self.changeoutro(1)).grid(row=4, column=c, sticky=ALL)
                elif c==2:
                    button2 = Button(self, text=buttons[c], command = lambda: self.changeoutro(2)).grid(row=4, column=c, sticky=ALL)
                elif c==3:
                    button3 = Button(self, text=buttons[c], command = lambda: self.changeoutro(3)).grid(row=4, column=c, sticky=ALL)           
                else:
                    button = Button(self, text=buttons[c], command = self.opener).grid(row=4, column=c, sticky=ALL)
                if c == 0 or c == 1:
                    l = Frame(self, bg=ard)

                    l.bind("<Button-1>", coordinates)

                    l.grid(row=c,column=0, rowspan=1, columnspan=2, sticky=ALL)

                elif c == 2:
                    l = Frame(self, bg=ard)
                    l.grid(row=0, column = 2, rowspan = 2, columnspan = 3, sticky = ALL)
                    self.enter = Entry(l, width=100)
                    self.enter.grid(row=0, column=2, rowspan=1, columnspan=3, sticky=ALL)
                    self.outro = Text(l, width=100, height=100)
                    self.outro.grid(row=1, column=2, rowspan=1, columnspan=3, sticky=ALL)



    def opener(self):
        message = []
        fname = self.enter.get()
        if os.path.isfile(fname):
            f = open(fname, 'r')
            for line in f:
                message.append(line)
            self.outro.insert(1.0, ' '.join(message))

    def changeoutro(self, c):
        self.outro.config(fg=buttons[c]) 
app = Application(master=root)             
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you're trying to accomplish, so I can't give a definitive solution. However, I see a common mistake or that leads to problems like the one you are describing.

First, you are creating a frame `l`, and you are using `grid` inside that frame to manage widgets. However, you aren't giving any rows or columns inside that frame a weight, so the widgets won't use any extra space in that frame. You need to call `rowconfigure` and `columnconfigure` to give a positive weight to at least one row and one column.

Note that if this frame only contains one entry and one text, it's a bit easier to use `pack` rather than `grid` for this specific frame. You can pack the entry to the top and the text to the bottom, and you don't have to worry about column weights:

```
self.enter.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=False)
self.outro.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand=True)
```

Second, it appears you might misunderstand how tkinter works. You are telling the entry widget to span two rows and three columns, yet that parent widget (`l`) only has a single column, and only two rows. When you use grid rows and columns, that apply only *within* the immediate parent window. It doesn't matter if your GUI as a whole has multiple rows and/or columns, when you place something in `l`, the rows and columns are only relative to the rows and columns within `l`.

In other words, there's no reason to use `columnspan` inside `l` since there's only one column, and for the same reason, there's no point in putting the entry and text widget in column 2.